# How do I disable the Nvidia GPU on a Dell Vostro 3500?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, laptop, gpu, hybrid-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Ubuntu website stipulates that Dell Vostro 3500 is a certified laptop with a condition that only integrated Intel GPU is used. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and it seems to be using Nvidia but not the integrated GPU. Although Nvidia seems to be working (I am using the latest Nvidia drivers from their website) I would still prefer to revert to Intel GPU due to lower power consumption. Could someone advise me the best way to do so? I am not an experienced Linux user and would appreciate if one could give me detailed instructions.

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: There is a method described (but ONLY for **Windows7**) at: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/p/19410604/19963428.aspx#19963428

Comment: If you have found a solution, consider adding/marking it. If not, close or delete?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that says that laptop comes with both. It likely comes with either Intel graphics or NVidia graphics. (there are a few laptops that come with both). What the page you are referencing is probably saying is that it is certified on the versions of laptops that come with Intel graphics, but not the ones with NVidia graphics.

For that reason, you won't be able to switch to Intel Graphics because it doesn't come with both.

Comment: Many high-end laptops have 'embedded' (low-power) graphics as well as a dedicated (power hungry) graphics chip.  This allows BOTH good battery life AND high-end graphics capability, but makes drivers much more complicated.

Comment: @david6 - Yes I know that some high-end laptops come with both (this is why I said that in my response). In my brief google searches on that particular laptop, I cannot find any trace of info that says this particular laptop comes with both an Intel AND NVidia graphics chip at the same time. Please let me know if you have information that says differently.

Comment: I did find: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/p/19410604/19963428.aspx#19963428  But I don't have Dell laptop to look at ..

Comment: From the Dell support site: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/vos3500/en/SM/specs.htm#wp1117848

Comment: Random PDF spec: http://www.floralimited.com/images/pdf/Vostro3500SpecSheetAPJEnglishFinal_1.27.pdf